# Is it Possible to Streamline / De-Clutter the Process of Importing Customized Fonts via Less?

Tags: css, fonts, less

I have six different font libraries I'd like to import into my webapp via `less`. This is taking up a fair amount of space and cluttering the `main.less` file in which I'm styling other elements. Is there a way that I can import custom fonts into a different file (like `fonts.less`), and then `@import` that into `main.less`?

What I've tried:

Without using mixins (I now know that I could shorten the process even further) I've coded the below snippet 6x for different fonts. It resides in `fonts.less`.

```
@font-face{
    font-family: 'Font1';
    src: url('fonts/titilliumtext1-WebFont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/titilliumtext1-WebFont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/titilliumtext1-WebFont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/titilliumtext1-WebFont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/titilliumtext1-WebFont.svg#webfont') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

At the end of `fonts.less` I've created six variables, one for each different font type. i.e. `@F1: Font1;` `@F2: Font2;` etc.

Then I `@import "fonts/fonts.less";` into my `main.less` file, and try to reference the variables I've created in different classes:

```
.class1{
  font-family: @F1; 
}
```

It doesn't work. While it doesn't give me errors, the webpage isn't picking up the correct style.

If I write all the bulky `@font-face` code directly into my `main.less` file, it works fine. Is there a way to write it in a different file and then import and / or reference it from `main.less`?

Cheers.

Comment: >and try to reference the variables I've created (`@F1` `@F2` etc). It doesn't work. - You'd better to show that code where you've actually tried to reference these variable (not just generic `@font-face` snippet as above).

Comment: @seven-phases-max: I added some elaboration based on your first comment. `fonts.less` is not included multiple times. As stated, I'm hoping to import it once into `main.less` and then reference the variables I created within it. I already checked the topics you've referenced. They don't answer my question.

Comment: >"If I write all the bulky @font-face code directly into my main.less file, it works fine" - Most likely this means that you need to correct the font paths. By default `urls` are relative to the master less file so it should actually work as you wrote it but probably you set some compiler option that may affect it? (`relative-urls` etc.) - Just check what is the font path in the generated CSS and if they are correct.

Comment: @seven-phases-max: That did it. I was writing the paths relative from where `fonts.less` resided vs. `main.less.`